# Javafx: получить строку TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, index

Как получить строку, зная её номер, и задать ей стиль (или добавить класс)?
Например, в таблице 10 строк, мне нужно в 3-ей поменять стиль (например, фон этой строки).

Выделить нужно строку не при создании таблицы, а после, когда таблица уже готова. Я нажимаю на кнопку, и подсвечивается красным 3-я строка.

Comment: как [вариант](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113253/how-to-style-a-table-cell-in-javafx2-using-css-without-removing-hover-selection)...

Comment: @Andrey А чем не устраивает второй вариант из ответа( кроме поломкой при scroll'е, которую при желании можно починить костылём )?

Comment: Добавьте к модели данных логическое поле "Выделен".
Меняйте в модели этот флаг когда будет угодно, а в рендерере поставьте в конструктор слушатель события изменения значения этого логического поля. При наступлении события пусть меняется стиль ячейки, содержащей экземпляр данных.

Answer (score 2):

Вот два в одном возможных варианта( второй работает только в момент исполнения, так что если хочется использовать его то нужно посадить на какой-нибудь листенер ):

```
public class Main2 extends Application {

    public static final int STYLING_ROW_INDEX = 3;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        File folder = new File( "/" );
        TableColumn<File,String> fileColumn = new TableColumn<File,String>( "Files" );
        TableView<File> table = new TableView<File>();
        table.getColumns().add( fileColumn );
        fileColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<File,String>( "name" ) );

        // вариант 1:
        table.setRowFactory( new StyleRowFactory<File>() );

        table.getItems().addAll(folder.listFiles());
        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene(table));
        primaryStage.show();

        // вариант 2( ломается при scroll'е ):
/*
        for ( Node n: table.lookupAll( "TableRow" ) ) {
            if ( n instanceof TableRow ) {
                TableRow row = (TableRow)n;
                if ( row.getIndex() == STYLING_ROW_INDEX ) {
                    row.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: red;" );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
*/
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch( args );
    }


}

class StyleRowFactory<T> implements Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> {

//    private final int stylingRowIndex;

//    public StyleRowFactory( int stylingRowIndex ) {
//        this.stylingRowIndex = stylingRowIndex;
//    }

    @Override
    public TableRow<T> call(TableView<T> tableView) {
        return new TableRow<T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem( T paramT, boolean b ) {
                if ( getIndex() == Main2.STYLING_ROW_INDEX ) {
//              if ( tableView.getItems().get( Main2.STYLING_ROW_INDEX ) == paramT ) {
                    setStyle( "-fx-background-color: red;" );
                } else {
                    setStyle( null );
                }
                super.updateItem(paramT, b);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Результат:

[image: result]

UPDATE: Вариант расширенный( как советовал @DimXenon ):

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList(
            new Person( "q" ),
            new Person( "w" ),
            new Person( "e" ),
            new Person( "r" ),
            new Person( "t" ),
            new Person( "y" ),
            new Person( "u" ),
            new Person( "i" )
        );

        TableColumn<Person,String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<Person,String>( "Человеки" );
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty );
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
        table.getColumns().add( nameColumn );
        table.getItems().setAll( persons );
        table.setRowFactory( new StyleRowFactory() );
        VBox.setVgrow( table, Priority.ALWAYS );

        Button button = new Button( "qwer" );
        button.setOnAction( ae -> {
            persons.get( 3 ).setHighlight( true );
// грязный хак, чтобы спровоцировать обновление
            nameColumn.setVisible( false );
            nameColumn.setVisible( true );
        } );

        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( new VBox( button, table ) ));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch( args );
    }
}

class StyleRowFactory implements Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>> {
    @Override
    public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> tableView) {
        return new TableRow<Person>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem( Person person, boolean b ) {
                super.updateItem( person, b );
                if ( person == null )
                    return;
                if ( person.isHighlight() ) {
                    setStyle( "-fx-background-color: red;" );
                } else {
                    setStyle( null );
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

class Person {
    public final StringProperty nameProperty;
    private final BooleanProperty highlightProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty( false );
    public Person( String name ) {
        nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty( name );
    }
    public void setHighlight( boolean value ) {
        highlightProperty.set( value );
    }
    public boolean isHighlight() {
        return highlightProperty.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к модели данных логическое поле "Выделен". Меняйте в модели этот флаг когда будет угодно, а в рендерере поставьте в конструктор слушатель события изменения значения этого логического поля. При наступлении события пусть меняется стиль ячейки, содержащей экземпляр данных.

Приведу код двух классов: первый класс - это наши данные, с определённым флагом "выделено"; второй класс - это рендерер ячеек.

```
    private class TableItem {

        private final BooleanProperty active;
        private final StringProperty content;

        public TableItem(String val) {
            this.active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
            this.content = new SimpleStringProperty(val);
        }

        public void setActive(boolean val) {
            this.active.setValue(val);
        }

        public BooleanProperty getActive() {
            return this.active;
        }

        public void setContent(String val) {
            this.content.setValue(val);
        }

        public StringProperty getContent() {
            return this.content;
        }
    }

    private static class NiceTableCell extends TableCell<String, TableItem> {

        public NiceTableCell() {
            super();
            BooleanProperty active = this.getItem().getActive();
            active.addListener((Observable c) -> {
                this.updateStyles(this.getItem());
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final TableItem item, final boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty ? "" : item.getContent().getValue());
            this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);");
            updateStyles(empty ? null : item);
        }

        private void updateStyles(TableItem item) {
            if (item == null) {
                return;
            }
            if(item.getActive().getValue()){
                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);");
            }
        }
    }
```

После создания `ObservableList<TableItem>` вы сможете менять для его элементов значение свойства `active` и содержащие их ячейки в таблице, которые рендерятся как `NiceTableCell` будут окрашиваться в красный цвет.